# How do I load and play audio files in a Java application

Tags: java, audio

I've googled around now for the last 2 hours and can't find a very basic way to load an audio file and play it when an action occurs in my program. I also need to be able to package my audio files into the final exported jar file so people can use the program and have the necessary audio resources.

Comment: [The Java Sound Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use javax.sound.sampled.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
```

This is the function I would use to load a "Clip".

```
public Clip loadClip( String filename )
{
    Clip in = null;

    try
    {
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( getClass().getResource( filename ) );
        in = AudioSystem.getClip();
        in.open( audioIn );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return in;
}
```

Just call it like

```
Clip sound = loadClip( "/sound.wav" );
```

The sound file has to be in a resource file (such as the default, src or my personal favorite, res).  I then make a function to play it:

```
public void playClip( Clip clip )
{
    if( clip.isRunning() ) clip.stop();
            clip.setFramePosition( 0 );
    clip.start();
}
```

I put this in an Art class so I would call it like

```
Art.playClip( Art.sound );
```

The code should be fairly self explanatory but in case it doesn't work, I have a video tutorial on how to do it (with an ironic sound bug causing it not to record) : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mafOKyWWTpY
Hope I have helped you!

Comment: Using this code, I get a null pointer exception when I call playClip(). It claims to occur when I try clip.start().

Comment: Actually, my issue was AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( getClass().getResource( filename ) ); needed to include a .getClassLoader() Congrats your method works for the time being :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Also, be careful with using MP3s.  Sound sampled is only compatible with a certain encryption so if it doesn't work, try a different encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If what you wan to do is accessing low level API, in most case rather not likely.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/

If you want to just play MP3 file, You'd better look at this.

http://www.morgenstille.at/blog/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-in-java-simple-and-beautiful/